# Offline Updates for macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: install, software-update, catalina

In the past, it was almost-always possible to get offline installers for Apple macOS updates from https://support.apple.com/downloads/ (you get a PKG file in a DMG file).

However the same doesn't seem to be true for Catalina. So far none of [the updates have been made available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Releases).

- Supplemental Update 19A602
- Revised Supplemental Update 19A603
- 10.15.1

At-least not in the usual place, they can only be installed using the built-in software updater.

Are these being made available for download somewhere, or is there any more information available on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sometime late yesterday or early today [the 10.15.1 update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2022) was made available for download (along with corresponding [10.14 Mojave Security Update 2019-001](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2024) and [10.13 High Sierra Security Update 2019-006](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2023) updates; 10.12 Sierra is likely retired now).

The 10.15 Supplemental Updates were never made available in this way for some reason, but the 10.15.1 update supersedes those updates anyhow. It remains to be seen if other 10.15 updates like the Security or Supplemental updates will continue to be available as they were in the past.

Comment: The latest security update for **macOS Sierra** was [Security Update 2019-005 (Sierra)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2013), posted on  Sep 26, 2019. I think only if we don't see another one after this can one say "10.12 Sierra must be retired now".

Comment: @user3439894 Could be. I figured since the release of 10.15 since then, they probably only release updates for the previous 2 versions.